# Java 8's orElse not working as expected

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Consider the following method which returns a field if it exists or recursively calls itself until the field is found:

```
private Field getField(Class<?> clazz, String p) {
    Optional<Field> field = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> p.equals(f.getName()))
            .findFirst();

    return field.isPresent() ? field.get() : getField(clazz.getSuperclass(), p);
}
```

While this works, I thought I could shorten it to:

```
private Field getField(Class<?> clazz, String p) {
    return Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> p.equals(f.getName()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(getField(clazz.getSuperclass(), p));
}
```

But the strange thing is that the `.orElse` part seems to always be called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you aware that if the field does not exist, you will hit a `null` superclass at some point?

Comment: @Holger Yes I know, I've just left that out to simplify the code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The arguments for a method are always evaluated before the method is called. You want `orElseGet` which takes a `Supplier` that will only be invoked if the `Optional` is not present:

```
private Field getField(Class<?> clazz, String p) {
    return Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> p.equals(f.getName()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> getField(clazz.getSuperclass(), p));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that the getField Method will be called before execution.