# Transforming Classes with Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I've been exploring transforming an object from one type of class to another with java 8.  What I have are a bunch of xjc generated jaxb classes.  The classes don't have a sufficiently friendly structure because they map the xml more structure rather than the business object structure.  I'm unwilling to edit the generated classes because I like to regenerate them whenever the schema changes without having to worry about retaining customizations.

I've got a schema something like:

```
<xs:element name="farm">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="animal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="animal">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="goat"/>
            <xs:element ref="sheep"/>
        </xs:sequence>
     <xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="goat">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            goat fields
        </xs:sequence>
     <xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="sheep">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            sheep fields
        </xs:sequence>
     <xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This generates Java something like:

```
class Farm
    public List<Animal> getAnimals()

class Animal

    public Goat getGoat()
        public String getGoatField()

    public Sheep getSheep()
        public String getSheepField()
```

`getGoat` and `getSheep` can return null, but they can't both be null.  Likewise, at least one of them must be null.  This is enforced via business rules and database constraints, but not in the xml (although if anyone has a suggestion to structure the xml more like the desired VOs I'm all ears)

I'd like to transform this class into

```
class FarmWrapper
    public ArrayList<AnimalVO> getAnimals()
    //optional features tbd
    //possibly public ArrayList<GoatVO> getGoats()
    //possibly public ArrayList<SheepVO> getSheep()

class GoatVO extends AnimalVO

class SheepVO extends AnimalVO
```

My idea was to do something like this:

```
herd.stream()
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.map(a -> {
    Optional<AnimalVO> goatVO = Optional.ofNullable(a.getGoat())
            .map(g ->  new GoatVO(g.getGoatField()));
    Optional<AnimalVO> sheepVO = Optional.ofNullable(a.getSheep())
            .map(s ->  new SheepVO(s.getSheepField()));
    return goatVO.orElse(sheepVO.get());
})
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Right now I've been feeding it a list, and as soon as it encounters a null sheep, it throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

I suppose I a few questions:

1. Is this an approach worth taking to split my list into classes that use inheritance?
2. What's the best way to use Optional to protect against incoming potentially null values, when you can't change the classes passing you nulls
3. What am I missing with `goatVO.orElse(sheepVO.get())` working as long as goatVO contains null and then throwing `NoSuchElementException` when sheepVO contains null

What I'm really doing is working with generated jaxb code and trying to take the generated classes and make the friendlier to work with.  Traditionally the project has used a wrapper class that transforms the generated classes to VOs via a substantial amount of null checking and int to BigInteger sort of manipulations.

Editing the generated classes (Goat, Sheep, Animal) is a non starter because I would like to retain the ability to regenerate without worrying

Comment: Why do you need `GoatVO` or `SheepVO` instead of just `Goat` and `Sheep`?

Comment: Your last question is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657306/java-8s-orelse-not-working-as-expected/31657522#31657522

Comment: I've edited the question to add more background about what I'm trying to do and what my constraints are

Comment: @Alex that question looks like it answers my "how do I beat this into shape question." Now onto whether I should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make your code work with a couple of adjustments:

```
List<AnimalVO> list = herd.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(a -> Optional.ofNullable(a.getGoat())
        .map(Goat::getGoatField)
        .<AnimalVO>map(GoatVO::new)
        .orElseGet(() -> new SheepVO(a.getSheep().getSheepField())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I prefer method references over lambdas, so I've switched to using them.

Note the hint to the compiler in `<AnimalVO>map(GoatVO::new)`. This is necessary to let the compiler know that the type you are mapping to is always an `AnimalVO`, otherwise it infers that the first `Optional` returns a `GoatVO` and gives a compilation error in the second `Optional`, which returns a `SheepVO` (and `SheepVO` is not a descendant of `GoatVO`).

Also note that I'm using `orElseGet()` method instead of `orElse()`. `orElseGet()` receives a `Supplier` of a default value, instead of the default value itself. This means that the default value is picked lazily, only when the value of the first `Optional` is not present.

---

**EDIT:** If you had more animals in your farm, i.e. apart from `Goat` and `Sheep`, now you have a `Cow`, this is how you could do it:

```
List<AnimalVO> list = herd.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(a -> Optional.ofNullable(a.getGoat())
        .map(Goat::getGoatField)
        .<AnimalVO>map(GoatVO::new)
        .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(a.getSheep())
            .map(Sheep::getSheepField)
            .<AnimalVO>map(SheepVO::new)
            .orElseGet(() -> new CowVO(a.getCow().getCowField()))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I had wondered how to do class casts in lambdas, the syntax escaped me

Comment: If `AnimalVO.class::cast` looks too weird or unfamiliar, you may rather use an ordinary cast in a lambda expression `x -> (AnimalVO)x`. But here, the cast isn’t necessary. It’s just that the inferred type of `.map(GoatVO::new)` is too narrow, so you may say `.<AnimalVO>map(GoatVO::new)` instead, telling the intended type explicitly. Then, no follow-up cast is needed.

Comment: @Holger True, the cast is unnecessary. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: As a side note, within the `orElseGet(…)` lambda, there is no need to use an `Optional` as the values are expected to be non-`null` in the case the `orElseGet` supplier is executed, not only by the question’s premise, but also as you are going to unconditionally invoke `get` on the optional anyway. So `.orElseGet(() -> new SheepVO(a.getSheep().getSheepField()))` would do as well. But of course, if the code gets extended to cover the entire farm, only the last animal alternative can be processed without an `Optional`.

Comment: I had to tweak the orElseGet to avoid the possibility of a.getSheep() being null, but apart from that it worked.  Off to measure results

Comment: @monknomo As Holger stated, you'd only have to check for a.getSheep() being null if you have more animals, which was my original version. You don't have to do that check for the last animal. Would you like me to post an example with more animals?

Comment: Sure, although I tried it and ran into an NPE without a null check in orElseGet with what I have.  I'm pretty sure I don't understand why the null check would be skippable

Comment: @monknomo Please see my edited answer. To avoid the null-check, I'm wrapping the next animal (`Sheep` in my example) in a nested `Optional` within the `orElseGet(...)` of the previous `Optional.

Comment: Hm, this code smacks mildly to me of prioritizing being stream-style over being readable, but I suppose that's down to developer preference.

Comment: @user508633 It's a matter of habit. While I agree that there's no need to take everything to stream-like, functional style, it's also true that after several years of imperative programming, most of us tend to see other non-imperative paradigms as exotic. Personally, I always try to be as clear as possible, my code as clean, compact and simple as possible, but also maintainable and readable for other developers. However, when answering questions here, I try to walk a mile in OP's shoes and go straight to the point of the question, rather than being "myself". :)

Comment: @user508633 I'm exploring a new way of doing things; I'm hardly set on streams.  I have a lot of these 'animals' that I want to transform and I had the idea that perhaps I could leverage parallel streams to make it faster.  I also was toying with using optional to reduce a ton of null checks.  So far it seems that I do not actually get any performance boost until something like 2000 instances to transform.  Certainly not unheard of my use case, but not the rule.  I may implement both techniques and use the size of my 'farm' to determine which transform technique to apply.

Answer (score 3):

1. Basically you can do it like that, although inheritance model would be better (`Sheep extends Animal`, `Goat extends Animal`)
2. If you want to protect against potential nulls, you can do `something = optionalValue.orElse(defaultValue)` which will return value contained by `Optional` if the value is not null, or `defaultValue` if the value in `Optional` is null
3. Line `goatVO.orElse(sheepVO.get())` throws `NoSuchElementException` because `sheepVO` contains `null`. Please note that `sheepVO.get()` evaluates regardless the value in `goatVO`.

Comment: Agreed on point 1, but I'm dealing with generated code that faithfully reproduces an XML document structure.  Point 3 is illuminating

Answer (score 2):

`return goatVO.orElseGet(sheepVO::get);`

The code is greedily trying to dereference the `sheepVO` optional, even when `goatVO` is present. This makes the second dereference lazy, so that it occurs only if `goatVO` is absent.

RE: your other two questions, I think converting to a guaranteed nonnull interface is great. That said, this is probably only helpful if your `AnimalVO` is actually a useful interface (i.e. your code doesn't actually care about which animal type it's working with). If your other code does care, you might want something like [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) to allow your consumers to work with the individual types.

Better yet, don't go too functional, and just collect your input into two waiting lists of `goats` and `sheeps`, and return that; which of these works best for your use case depends hugely on how these types are actually used, so that's probably up to you to decide.

Comment: Eh, I've got a whole "farm". Sometimes I care about the particular animal type but sometimes I don't. Depends on context. This is still a toy to explore what I want to do with the real deal

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this Inheritance thing wrong... Why not just write

```
abstract class Animal {abstract public AnimalVO createVO();}
class Sheep extends Animal {public SheepVO createVO(){...}}
class Goat extends Animal {public GoatVO createVO(){...}}
```

Then if you want all the VOs for the animals you just

```
List<Animal> animals = ...;
List<AnimalVO> vos = animals.stream().map(Animal::createVO).collect(toList());
```

If you can explain a bit *what* you want to achieve, we can look at *how* to achieve it.

Comment: That would be preferable but I'm attempting to wrap generated code with something friendly